# Sed regex not matching 'either or' inner group

Tags: regex, sed, regex-group

I would like to match multiple file extensions passed through a pipe using sed and regex.

The following works:

```
sed '/.\(rb\)\$/!d'
```

But if I want to allow multiple file extensions, the following does *not* work.

```
sed '/.\(rb\|js\)\$/!d'
sed '/.\(rb|js\)\$/!d'
sed '/.(rb|js)\$/!d'
```

Any ideas on how to do either/or inner groups?

Here is the whole block of code:

```
#!/bin/sh
files=`git diff-index --check --cached $against | # Find all changed files
       sed '/.\(rb\|js\)\$/!d'                  | # Only process .rb and .js files
       uniq`                                      # Remove duplicate files
```

Comment: Why are you using `\$`instead of `$`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using a Mac OSX 10.8.3 and the previous answer does not work for me, but this does:

```
sed -E '/\.(rb|js)$/!d'
```

Note: use `-E` to

> Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions
>   rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).

and this enables the OR function `|`; other versions seem to want the `-r` flag to enable extended regular expressions.
Note that the initial `.` must be escaped and the trailing `$` must not be.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
sed '/\.\(rb\|js\)$/!d'
```

or if you have then use `-r` option to use extended regular expression for avoiding escaping special character.

Comment: There are [a good overview and tutorial for sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-30) and a [the same for the respective regular expressions](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html).